# Changing ViewModel Property, in another class Doesn't Update UI

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm having this issuse in a more complex App so I built a simple App to test it out on. but first the code, which is an odd layout for a simple app but bare in mind that this mimics my other app.

Note, Baseviewmodel inherits from basemodel.

**MainPage**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Class="TestINotify.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestINotify">
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel />
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <StackLayout>
    <!--  Place new controls here  -->
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
           Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
           Text="{Binding LabelTextProperty}"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Button Command="{Binding ChangeTextCommand}" Text="Change Label Text" />

  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPageViewModel**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand ChangeTextCommand { private set; get; }

    private string _labelText = "Default text" ;

    public string LabelTextProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _labelText;

        }
        set
        {
            _labelText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        ChangeTextCommand = new Command(execute: () =>
        {
            var handler = new ChangeTextClass();
            handler.ChangeTexts();

        });

    }

}
```

**ChangeTextClass**

```
    public class ChangeTextClass
    {
        public MainPageViewModel mpvm = new MainPageViewModel();
        public void ChangeTexts()
        {
            mpvm.LabelTextProperty = "The Text Was Changed ?";

        }
    }
```

**BaseModel**

```
public abstract class BaseModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

When i assign the label's text value in the viewmodel by

```
    ChangeTextCommand = new Command(execute: () =>
    {
       LabelTextProperty = "Local works";

    });
```

It works fine but, so maybe it's be something to do with me creating a new instances of the viewmodel in the class ?

Comment: Are you sure it is the same instance of the ViewModel?

Comment: No it's a new instance (new mainviewmodel(), how would I retrieve the old instances ?

Comment: One way is define a static instance of your MainPageViewModel somewhere in your app(Say in App.cs) and in MainPageViewModel's constructor fill this static instance like this: App.MainPageVM = this;
And change properties of this static instance wherever in your project.